# what is the meaning of LDR pc,[pc,#reset]

Tags: assembly, arm

```
LDR pc,[pc,#reset]
```

This peace of code used in vector tables in the book I am studying this days. we know that "pc" is the address of instruction to fetch,(program counter),but when using as first argument of LDR instruction, it violate *pc*'s address nature.

Comment: Well, what do you think would happen if the PC register was loaded with a value?

Comment: @Ross Ridge:I am just confusing .. If we load pc by value of its pointing address , jump to wrong area or nowhere!!(where there is no instruction there or out of range)

Comment: What value to do think gets loaded into PC, and why do you think it would lead to a jump to the wrong area or nowhere?

Comment: Let me know say by example:

Comment: Let me know say by example: in address of 0x0001204F  there is value of 0x00000001. I run LDR pc,[pc,#0]. I assume pc is 0x0001204F. so after instruction run pc=0x00000001. What this help to vector table??

Comment: pc = mem( pc + #reset ). you jump to the #reset's entry in the address table that's below this commend. the values below must be - of course - valid addresses, so #0 wouldn't make sense

Comment: It's just a load instruction with immediate offset and the destination as the program counter, that means the next instruction run will be at the address just loaded in. No different to loading an address into a register and then branching to it unconditionally.

Comment: Lets say at the address denoted by the symbol `reset` there is stored the address of a reset routine. Lets also say the assembler will assemble an instruction form of `LDR Rt,[pc,#label]` into an PC relative LDR instruction. The destination operand is `Rt`, a register, and the source operand is `[pc,#label]` a PC relative memory operand. The later encoded by the assembler using the correct PC relative offset so that the source memory operand is the memory location denoted by the symbol `label`. So given all this, where does `LDR pc,[pc,#reset]` jump to?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by violating anything.  You really should just read the ARM documentation rather than asking us to do it for you.

Just looking at the syntax

```
ldr Rt,[Rn,#immed]
```

It is going to take the value in Rn use it as an address, add the immediate and read a word from that location, then place that value read in Rt. If Rt is R15 (the program counter) then it branches.  Whether or not you can use this to change between arm and thumb modes is specific to the architecture you are using (ARMv4, ARMv5, ARMv6, etc).  Plus other exceptions.

If you do a writeback

```
ldr Rt,[Rn,#immed]!
```

Then I think you get the unpredictable result you deserve.

In arm mode R15 is two instructions ahead (well it is always two instructions ahead).  So if this ldr is at address 0x100 then when it executes Rn will be 0x108 it will add the immediate then jump to the result, so this could be used as a really lazy way to make a compile (assemble) time jump table

```
.equ BOB  ,  0x0
.equ CAROL,  0x4
.equ TED  ,  0x8
.equ ALICE,  0xC
nop
.align 8
ldr pc,[pc,#TED]
.word 0
.word bob
.word carol
.word ted
.word alice
.align 8
bob:
    nop
    nop
    b .
ted:
    nop
    b .
carol:
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    b .
alice:
    b .
```

which creates this table

```
 100:   e59ff008    ldr pc, [pc, #8]    ; 10 <bob-0x1f0>
 104:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
 108:   00000200    andeq   r0, r0, r0, lsl #4
 10c:   00000214    andeq   r0, r0, r4, lsl r2
 110:   0000020c    andeq   r0, r0, r12, lsl #4
 114:   00000228    andeq   r0, r0, r8, lsr #4
```

0x108+8 = 0x110 which gives address 0x20C which will be loaded into R15 and cause a jump to that address

```
00000200 <bob>:
 200:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 204:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 208:   eafffffe    b   208 <bob+0x8>

0000020c <ted>:
 20c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 210:   eafffffe    b   210 <ted+0x4>

00000214 <carol>:
 214:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 218:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 21c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 220:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
 224:   eafffffe    b   224 <carol+0x10>

00000228 <alice>:
 228:   eafffffe    b   228 <alice>
```

Now if I change this line to

```
ldr pc,[pc,#CAROL]
```

and re-assemble it branches to a different address.  Would have been much easier to just

```
b ted
```

and then change that to

```
b alice
```

*IF* you can reach those with a branch, slightly cheaper otherwise to

```
ldr pc,=ted
```

and replace that with

```
ldr pc,=carol
```

if you want to do an assemble time change that can reach anywhere, and doesnt have any if armv4 then if armv5 then etc nuances (other than switching to thumb or not).